# docker compose command with export echo

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Please help me make this work.

I'm attaching a volume dir and want this volume dir's *.jars to be exported as env.

- I don't want an extra volume this is why an entry point script isn't an option.

```
services:
  # Spark Master
  spark-master:
    container_name: spark-master
    image: spark-341-ndb
    environment:
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=2424
      - SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=9292
    ports:
      - "2424:2424"
      - "9292:9292"
    volumes:
      - /home/my_spark_repo/spark-defaults.conf:/opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
      - /home/my_spark_repo/spark_db:/opt/spark_db
    networks:
      - spark-network
    command: bash -c 'export SPARK_EXECUTOR_EXTRACLASSPATH=$$(echo /opt/spark_db/*.jar | tr " " ":") && exec /opt/spark/bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master'
```

I have tried a lot of things.

Comment: maybe add an error log ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this via an entrypoint wrapper script.  You should add this to the image itself.

The script will be passed the main container command as arguments.  Do whatever first-time setup you need to do, then uses the shell construct `exec "$@"` to switch to the main container command.  For example:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

for f in "/opt/spark_db/*.jar"; do
  SPARK_EXECUTOR_EXTRACLASSPATH="$SPARK_EXECUTOR_EXTRACLASSPATH:$f"
done
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_EXTRACLASSPATH

exec "$@"
```

In the Dockerfile, `COPY` this script into the image, make it be the `ENTRYPOINT`, and set the `CMD` to the second half of that command.

```bash
COPY docker-entrypoint /opt/spark/bin
ENV PATH=/opt/spark/bin:$PATH
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["spark-class", "org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master"]
```

The entrypoint script will re-run every time the container starts, so if the container restarts with a volume with a different set of jar files, the environment variable will have different values.  You can double-check this by running a temporary container with a different command; the entrypoint wrapper will stay in place but the command will change.

```bash
docker-compose run spark-master \
  sh -c 'echo $SPARK_EXECUTOR_CLASSPATH'
```

Also consider `COPY` the jar files into the image, making it self-contained, rather than injecting a significant required part of your application at runtime via volumes.